# How can I get subtitle with video without srt file?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to create a player that will automatically show subtitle in bottom bar at same time with video. I didn't get any option. I tried Google tap on but it will show text/sentence later after completion of period.

Answer (score 0):

Read here : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Multimedia

Above V4.0, Media Player does support!

Here is an example using

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

try {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    mediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(subTitleSrc, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
    int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(
            MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo());
    if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
        mediaPlayer.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
    } else {
        Log.w("test", "Cannot find text track!");
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, final TimedText timedText) {
            if (timedText != null) {
                Log.d("test", "subtitle: " + timedText.getText());
            }
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

And if you wanna support pre v4.0 follow this link

https://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/subtitle-support